# How to create group and add to checkbox rather than selection in Odoo 10?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I have tried to create the security group as check box. But it is coming as a selection only. The code is give below.

```
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_ga">
        <field name="name">GA Access Rights</field>
        <field name="sequence">205</field>
    </record>

    <record id="group_directors" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Directors</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_ga"/>
    </record>
```

This is the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use a module category if you want it as a checkbox.

```xml
    <record id="group_directors" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Directors</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: No. It is not changed. Still it shows in a selection field. @CZoellner

Comment: You have to remove the Category by yourself or just add `<field name="category_id" />`